# Approximation Algorithm- using expectation

Tags: algorithm, math, probability, approximation

Note: You don't have to understand Approximation Algorithms to answer this

Hello. 

 I need to prove an algorithm approximation by using expectation.

 The algorithm takes `x_i \in {0,1,2}` such that `i\in 1,...n+2` and there are constants `c_i \in 0,1,2` such that `i\in 1,...,n` and would like to find an assignment to the variables such that `x_i +x_(i+1)+x_(i+2) !=  0 \mod(3)`  for all `i` such that the number of indexes such that `x_i +x_(i+2) = c_i \mod(3)` is maximized. 

 it does the following:

choose `x_1 , x_2 \in 0,1,2` independently and uniformly at random and then

 for each `i\in 3,...,n+2` given the values of `x_(i-2),x_(i-1)` assign to `x_i` one of two values in `{b\in 0,1,2 | x_(i-1)+x_(i-2)+b != 0 \mod(3)}` 
uniformly at random. 

the assignment to each `x_i` is independent for all `x_j` such the `j<i-2`. 


I need to prove this algorithm gives a `1/3` approximation to the problem described, using expectation(meaning proving that for some X random variable that we assign to this question, `E[X]=1/3`)

 I am struggling with defining such X and calculating this, I keep getting 2\3 instead of 1\3.

 can anyone help with the calculation?

Answer (score 1):

You can prove that each x_i is uniformly distributed over {0, 1, 2} and pairwise independent by induction. The base case (n=2) is immediate, and the induction step follows from the fact you're given x_i being independent from x_j (with j < i-2), and a simple enumeration of cases.

The result follows immediately, since P(x_i + x_{i+2} = c_i) is 1/3, and by linearity of expectation, E[X] = n/3.

Clarifying the last statement: Let V_i be a random variable such that V_i is 1, if x_i + x_{i+2} = c_i. Otherwise, V_i is 0. Then X = sum(V_i i=1..n), and E[X] = sum(E[V_i] i=1..n) by linearity of expectation. However, E[V_i] = P(x_i + x_{i+2} = c_i) = 1/3.

Comment: why does X= sum(V_i) ?

Comment: I took "X is the RV that we assign to this question" to mean that it's the RV that's the number of times that x_i + x_{i+2} == c_i. The V_i are indicators for each of the individual cases, and X is their sum.

Comment: but how come? like where the condition for which x_i +x_(i+1)+x_(i+2)!= 0 \mod(3)